# Which MySQL column should be set as index

Tags: mysql, database, select, optimization, indexing

I received an email from my server host telling me that I had to optimize my database requests which seem to be too slow.

Indeed, I use a lot of custom requests within Wordpress and these requests are pointing towards the "wp_postmeta" table. This is not ideal because you have to deal with the table structure as it is given.

Here are the columns within the 'wp-postmeta' table:

```
meta_id    (table id)
post_id    (related post which is a foreign key)
meta_key   (name of the parameter)
meta_value (value of that parameter)
```

meta_id is the default **primary key** of the table and there is **NO** index by default that is set by Wordpress.

I believe then that **the best way to optimize the requests** would be to assign an index to one of these columns.

So here is the most frequent request that I have:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'xxxx' and post_id = 1234
```

Knowing that:

- A same post_id can have up to 15 different related meta_keys and there are about 900 different post_id's
- A same meta_key can appear more than 150 times on the table records, whatever the post_id's

Which one of these two columns will be the best choice as the index of the table: **post_id** or **meta_key**?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend creating an index based on both columns, given that your most frequent statement 
is

```
SELECT FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'xxxx' and post_id = 1234
```

MySQL have some good documentation on the subject: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

```
CREATE INDEX index_postmeta_postmeta ON wp_postmeta (post_id, meta_key)
```

But basically, what an index does, and why you should use it is explained here: [What is an index in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955459/what-is-an-index-in-sql)

Your local friendly DBA should be doing all this for you BTW :)

Also, this is my personal rule of thumb. I create indexes on ALL foreign keys on a table, because it's usually a natural look up column. So I'd probably also chuck in:

```
 CREATE INDEX index_postmeta_postid ON wp_postmeta (post_id)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but doesn't it ruin the purpose of an index? I mean two indexes when you have 10 columns, I can understand that but two indexes for only 4 columns (50% is indexed), will it really optimize the queries? Thank you. PS: there is no administrator, there is only me so I am the one that should take care of this.

Comment: Nopes, because as you stated, your most frequent statement uses both those columns. So you don't want the platform performing a full table scan [when the platform looks at record 1 - current record] (which is what makes the query non-optimal) every time it executes that query. If needed, you can create separate indexes on both post_id and meta_key, if you're searching solely on those columns alone, frequently. Basically, you index based on your most frequently executed search conditions.

Comment: Ok, I see your edited post. Now you tell me that 3 indexes on 4 columns is the way to go! I trust your experience and I'll do that but it really seems weird. To me it's like saying that you want to optimize the execution of 4 things by giving priority n°1 to each of these things. From my noob point of view, priority 1 to everything is like doing nothing eventually. But I'll do that because you know better.

Comment: Eh? I've only suggested the creation of 2 indexes.
index_postmeta_postmeta, which uses 2 columns. And index_postmeta_postid, which is an index on post_id.
The last index is optional, as I said. But generally foreign keys are natural lookup points. As in you will query based on them. This is just a general rule of thumb :)