# SQLError:Can't DROP Index_name; check that column/key exists -- occurs multiple times

Tags: mysql

I want to execute a alter command on a table, create table and alter table commands are as below.

```
CREATE TABLE `xyz` (
      `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `masterform_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `app_status` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
      `NegativeMarks` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ActualScore` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `RawScore` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `PANProratedMarks` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `PANNormalizedMarks` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `RRBZoneNormalizedMarks` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,
      `RRBZoneProratedMarks` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,  
      `RRBZoneAllocationTempStorage` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `GraduatePercentage` decimal(15,5) DEFAULT NULL,
        `PANAllocationTempStorage` varchar(1500) DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`entity_id`),
      UNIQUE KEY `app_seq_no` (`app_seq_no`),
      UNIQUE KEY `ParticipantID` (`ParticipantID`),
      UNIQUE KEY `RegistrationNo` (`RegistrationNo`),  
      KEY `idx_PANNormalizedMarks` (`PANNormalizedMarks`),  
      KEY `idx_RRBZoneNormalizedMarks` (`RRBZoneNormalizedMarks`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=273252 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC


Alter table xyz
    modify column ActualScore decimal(15,5),
    modify column app_status varchar(500),
    add index CalculatedCategory(CalculatedCategory),
    modify column GraduatePercentage decimal(15,5),
    modify column NegativeMarks decimal(15,5),
    modify column PANAllocationTempStorage varchar(1500),
    modify column PANNormalizedMarks decimal(15,5),
    modify column PANProratedMarks decimal(15,5),
    drop index idx_ParticipantID,
    add unique ParticipantID(ParticipantID),
    modify column RawScore decimal(15,5),
    drop index idx_RegistrationNo,
    add unique RegistrationNo(RegistrationNo),
    modify column RRBZoneNormalizedMarks decimal(15,5),
    modify column RRBZoneProratedMarks decimal(15,5);
```

I am getting this error:

```
SQLError:Can't DROP 'idx_ParticipantID'; check that column/key exists
```

But I am getting this same 104 times. Could you please let me know why am I getting this error 104 times in log? If the index doesnt exist it should just give the error once, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: If i try your create Statement i get error message `Key column 'app_seq_no' doesn't exist in table`

Comment: @Jens you can ignore the keys, I have edited it in my script. Please let me know why the error message occurs so many times.

Comment: Because there is no index with this name. Also you should provide an [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

After creating table `xyz`, you are supposed to create the wanted indexes, one of them is idx_ParticipantID (an index on the column `ParticipantID`). But you didn't create that one, that's why you can't drop it.

But you can ignore those errors, they have no effect on your database.
I advise you to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955459/what-is-an-index-in-sql) some about indexes.

Comment: Agreed with you, but why does the error message occur multiple times. Ideally, it should occur only once, right?

Comment: try removing ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC because only for my_isam and clean the log file and retry

Comment: removing ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC didnt work..Also I tried it again and got this error only once. Does large number of data in the table have any impact on this?

Comment: No, data has no effect on that. But I think this may be due to the concatenation on the log file. So don't worry, keep moving:)