# I've indexed a combined column, should I index separate column too?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `cid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `name` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `desc` varchar(500),
    `deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `createdAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY `pid_cid` (`pid`,`cid`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

`WHERE` clause of select queries are those:

```
where pid=pid [and deleted = 1];
where cid=cid [and deleted = 1];
where pid=pid and cid=cid [and deleted = 1];
```

1. Should I index `pid` and `cid` separately?
2. Should I index `deleted`?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955459/what-is-an-index-in-sql and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1108/how-does-database-indexing-work

Comment: It's really odd to have a column called id that *isn't* primary

Comment: And in my view, calling a column desc is just asking for trouble

Comment: And why would name be int !?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The optimal set of indexes would be:

- `pid, deleted`
- `cid, deleted`
- `pid, cid, deleted`

Whether you need all three depends on your data.  How many different deleted values are there for each `pid`/`cid`.  The first two may be sufficient.

Indexing `deleted` by itself is probably not useful.  Presumably, it only takes on two values, which is generally not a good candidate for an index.