# Increase performance of a one-to-many join

Tags: mysql, performance

We're building a model where we're joining a 13-part profile (`01_01_resource_utilization_prepared`) to a daily record to create 13 record per day; this is a deliberate one-to-many which grows the size of the table.

It is a simple query but we have tried indexing but what is the best way to optimise this query?

```
SELECT
a.DATE,
a.RUN_ID,
a.HOURS,
a.HOURS * b.RESOURCE_DISTRIBUTION,
a.SCHEDULE_PROFILE_ID,
a.WEEKDAY_NUMBER,
a.SCHEDULE_DISTRIBUTION,
b.RESOURCE_DISTRIBUTION,
a.LOCATION_DESC,
a.DEPARTMENT_DESC,
a.LANGUAGE_DESC,
a.JOB_TITLE_DESC,

FROM
03_01_schedule a
LEFT JOIN 01_01_resource_utilization_prepared b ON (
    a.RESOURCE_PROFILE_ID = b.RESOURCE_PROFILE_ID
    AND a.DATE >= b.EFFECTIVE_FROM
    AND a.DATE <= b.EFFECTIVE_TO
)
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. There's a few important pieces of information we need to help. The schemas of the tables involved, please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50750735/edit) with the output of [`show create table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html) for each table in the query. This will show us the types and what is indexed, a key to performance. It will also help to see the [`explain` for that statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html). Finally, show us a sample of your input and the output you want.

Answer (score 1):

Does `01_01` refer to Jan 01?  If so, I suggest that is a bad way to lay out the data.  But meanwhile...

Checking for within a range, where the range comes from another table is hard to optimize.  These composite indexes on `b` will help a little:

```
INDEX(RESOURCE_PROFILE_ID, EFFECTIVE_FROM)
INDEX(RESOURCE_PROFILE_ID, EFFECTIVE_TO)
```

Is `LEFT` needed?  If it can be removed without destroying the semantics, then a much better option avails itself.  Removing `LEFT` would let this be useful on `a`:

```
INDEX(RESOURCE_PROFILE_ID, `DATE`)
```

(Meanwhile, I did not understand the relevance of anything you said in your first paragraph.)

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I can't say exactly, but performance will depend on [indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955459/what-is-an-index-in-sql) the columns you're comparing. Without indexes the join may have to scan every row, a ["full table scan"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_table_scan).

It's pretty common in MySQL to forget to [declare foreign keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html). `03_01_schedule.RESOURCE_PROFILE_ID` and `01_01_resource_utilization_prepared.RESOURCE_PROFILE_ID` should be declared as foreign keys and they will be indexed. This will make the basic join much faster and also supply referential integrity.

`03_01_schedule.DATE`, `01_01_resource_utilization_prepared.EFFECTIVE_FROM`, and `01_01_resource_utilization_prepared.EFFECTIVE_TO` should all be indexed. This will make comparisons using those columns much faster.

Comment: A FK implicitly creates an `INDEX` if one does not already exist.  Because an FK implies a constraint to check, it actually slows down the code a little (even assuming that the index exists).

Comment: `INDEX(a), INDEX(b)` is _not_ the same as `INDEX(a,b)`.  In many cases (including this one) the composite key is _better_.

Comment: @RickJames Yes, I worded that bit about FKs and indexes poorly. I'll fix that. As for the specific indexes, without more information it's hard to know.