# How to save custom id with custom order without synchronisation issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model object in my Rails application, let's call it Picture.

The pictures table in database has a primary key column called `id` because Rails create them automatically according to convention, this column is just 1, 2, 3, 4.....

But I need another column called `custom_id` to record its custom ID, I want its value to be

- `PIC2015-0001`, `PIC2015-0002`, `PIC2015-0003` for year 2015
- `PIC2018-0001`, `PIC2018-0002`, `PIC2018-0003` for year 2018
- and so on.

Basically `PICYYYY-NUM_FOR_YEAR`, where `YYYY` is the year it is created, and `NUM_FOR_YEAR` is the number this record is created (first record created in a year will have 0001, second will have 0002, and so on... This number will restart for new record each new year)

I want to implement this by using the after_create hook and look up its created_at time stamp to get the year `YYYY`, and infer the `NUM_FOR_YEAR` by looking at last Picture with non-empty `custom_id`. But I'm worried about synchronisation issue. What if the below happen (or will it happen at all?):

The below events happen in the time order listed

- Picture 1 created, after_create called and finished
- Picture 2 created
- Picture 3 created
- Picture 2 after_create called - fetch Picture 1's custom_id
- Picture 3 after_create called - fetch Picture 1's custom_id
- Picture 2 after_created finished
- Picture 3 after_created finished - this will have duplicate ID, which is wrong

What is the simplest way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to "fetch Picture 1's custom_id"?... Maybe you can use the callback `after_create_commit`, in there get the ID generated from  your DB, and from there update the  `custom_id`

[Read here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#transaction-callbacks)

Comment: Wouldn't using `after_create_commit` cause the same synchronisation problem? (Or it won't?) Also you said use the ID generated from your DB, but I want to restart from 0001 every year. Can you clarify your implementation so I can understand why it might address the problem I have?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, I forgot about that (restarting the count every year). Maybe, use a unique index at the DB level, at least this way you guarantee not to repeat a custom_id, the DB will raise an error if you try to duplicate the  value. As far as preventing the sync problem, at the application level, maybe with a `unique` validation in your model (then again this actually don't prevent the sync problem, but at least you are safe with the DB constraint)

Comment: Thank you, the DB level unique constraint is really helpful

Comment: Do you know how I can add DB level unique constraint to a column in a table in Rails? I googled but those answer seems to involve index, and I don't want to touch  index because I'm not sure if it will have bad side effect.

Comment: What if a record gets destroyed? How do you want to manage this case? Soft delete?

Comment: I assume records won't be deleted

Comment: In this case and assuming also no concurrent create, just pick the year from `created_at` and count records where created_at  this_year, build the string and save to `custom_id`. How fast is the data saving? You reserved 4 digits for a whole year, so it is 10000 records = 1,15 per hour. I wouldn't worry of concurrency, but better set unique constraint as validation.

Comment: If your column will be an id, why don't use index? I don't see a reason why not to do it. [Check this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2955470/8267417)

Comment: The reason is detailed in this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/51605107/6359753