# How to implement binary search in database table?

Tags: node.js, database, algorithm

I am making a simple sign up and login page in node js using sequelize(MySQL). I want to know how to implement sorting in the database on the username field during insertion operation and then use binary search to find a specific username in the database and return the index. I don't want actual code solution but any tutorial links or official docs that can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? The DBMS already implements searching algorithms and usually picks a good one to find a record. That's part of the point why one uses a DBMS.

Comment: Well, index your columns instead of implementing your own.

Comment: @stickybit So, if I run the query Sequelize.find on usernames in the table, it will automatically implement searching algorithms? That is binary search instead of linear search going from 1st index till last?

Comment: @vivek_23 I am sorry I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @DhruvSingh: Sequelize should not search for itself, it asks the DBMS to find the record. And the DBMS has means implemented to find the record. To help the DBMS using fast searching algorithms you should create proper indexes on the tables.

Comment: Proper indexes as in? My table has fields Id, username and password.

Comment: That depends on your search criteria.

Comment: I want to search for a specific username in username column.

Comment: @DhruvSingh You can index your column in the database for fast search instead of implementing binary search on your own. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955459/what-is-an-index-in-sql

Comment: @DhruvSingh: Then create an index on that column. For further info you should do a research on that topic. There are plenty of sources discussing indexing. That is to broad to handle that in the comments here.

Comment: Alright, I will check that. Thanks