# CASE query optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, case

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 1 THEN 1 END) AS score_1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 2 THEN 1 END) AS score_2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 3 THEN 1 END) AS score_3,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 4 THEN 1 END) AS score_4,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 5 THEN 1 END) AS score_5,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 6 THEN 1 END) AS score_6,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 7 THEN 1 END) AS score_7,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 8 THEN 1 END) AS score_8,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 9 THEN 1 END) AS score_9,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN VALUE = 10 THEN 1 END) AS score_10
FROM
  `answers`
WHERE
`created_at` BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-11-30 23:59:59'
```

Is there a way to optimize this query, because I have 4 million answer records in my DB, and it runs very slowly?

Comment: What's very slowly? Do you have an index on created_at?And I suspect sum would be better than count.

Comment: Use `SELECT COUNT() GROUP BY VALUE`, then pivot it using CASEs.

Comment: Unlikely that the `CASE` statement is the problem here. If indexes are lacking, your request involves a full table scan, that is 4 million records. Add `explain` in front of your statement to see the execution plan. Also, the resultset may be heavy in terms of data since your query spans almost 3 years. And the data has to travel over the network to reach your front-end.

Comment: No index is likely to help on any variation of this query.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this one time to create an index:

`CREATE INDEX ix_ca on answers(created_at)`

That should speed your query up. If you are curious about why, see here:

[What is an index in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955459/what-is-an-index-in-sql)

Comment: That index _probably won't_ be used -- assuming that a lot of the table is in that date range, hence it would be faster to ignore the index and simply scan the table.  (For a _short_ time span, the index would help a lot.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try add  a redundant composite index

```
create idx1 on table answers(created_at, value)
```

using redudance in index  the query should be result without accessing to table data just using the index  content

Comment: This "covering index" _may_ be moderately faster than a table scan.

Answer (score 0):

Want it to be 10 times as fast?  Use the Data Warehousing technique of buiding and maintaining a "Summary table".  In this example the summary table might be

```
CREATE TABLE subtotals (
    dy DATE NOT NULL,
    `value` ... NOT NULL,   -- TINYINT UNSIGNED ?
    ct SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, -- this is 2 bytes, max 65K; change if might be bigger
    PRIMARY KEY(value, dy)  -- or perhaps the opposite order
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Each night you summarize the day's data and build 10 new rows in `subtotals`.

Then the "report" query becomes

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 1 THEN ct END) AS score_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 2 THEN ct END) AS score_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 3 THEN ct END) AS score_3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 4 THEN ct END) AS score_4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 5 THEN ct END) AS score_5,
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 6 THEN ct END) AS score_6,
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 7 THEN ct END) AS score_7,
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 8 THEN ct END) AS score_8,
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 9 THEN ct END) AS score_9,
  SUM(CASE WHEN VALUE = 10 THEN ct END) AS score_10
FROM
  `subtotals`
WHERE `created_at` >= '2017-01-01'
  AND `created_at`  < '2019-12-01'
```

Based on what you have provided, there will be about 10K rows in `subtotals`; that's a lot less to wade through than 4M rows.  It might run more than 10 times as fast.

More discussion: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables