# Entity Framework Contains method when I know the database contains all of the HashSet's elements

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a table that contains objects from type person, each person has a unique column of type string called `id`, and I have a hashset of `Id`'s that I want to fetch the person's object for.

I thought I could do it efficiently by doing this:

```
HashSet<string> ids = //Some HashSet of ids

var idsHashSet = DbContext.Persons.Select(p => p.Id).ToHashSet();
idsHashSet.IntersectWith(ids);
var result = DbContext.Persons.Where(p => idsHashSet.Contains(p.Id)).ToList());
```

I saw in the database itself that the query being sent is:

```
SELECT <something> 
FROM <something> 
WHERE p.name IN ('id1', 'id2', id3'...)
```

And it's not efficient because I already know that each element in the HashSet is present in the database, so I wanted to know, is there a more efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to shorten your code:

```
var result = DbContext.Persons
    .Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Id))
    .ToList();
```

But it will be converted to the exact same SQL query, though, which is efficient enough.

Comment: @Dr.Work index might also help with efficiency and performance

Comment: @T.Dominik What do you mean by index?

Comment: @Dr.Work you can read about indexes in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2955459/what-is-an-index-in-sql).

Answer (score 0):

"And it's not efficient because I already know that each element in the HashSet is present in the database"  I'm not sure what you mean by this....the db has no idea if all the ids are present or not, regardless of whether you do.

How large is the set of ids?  Safer to create a temp table with the IDs and return a JOIN select if it's very large...otherwise I Don't see an issue with your query as it is.